# I'm not able to install opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to install OpenCV so that I can use it projects and whatnot but after downloading it from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/
I'm still getting these errors

```py
import cv2
```

**Error**

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

Comment: Where are you trying to install it? Anaconda or your system installation? Installing it with pip or conda will be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After downloading a package you have to install it with [The Python Package Installer](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/)

Answer (score 0):

Open a cmd window. Follow thes commands on your cmd.

```
python -m pip install numpy
python -m pip install opencv-python
```

You can visit the official site for documentation. It will be helpful for you. https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d00/tutorial_py_root.html
Hope your problem will be solved.
Thanks. Good Luck